# CSS grid with variable items, variable width and placeholder items

Tags: html, css, grid

I am trying to build a grid with variable width(based on viewport size) containing items, variable in quantity.
The grid can also contain placeholder-items, where no real item is present.

I made an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/1e6301q1/) trying to illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

The grid should also fulfill the following:

- A “row” should always be filled up with placeholder-items (if they fit).
- There should be no row only containing placeholder-items

One Problem with my solution e.g. at 350px:
The grid with 1 item, grid with 2 items and grid with 3 items have an extra row with only one placeholder. There should be no extra row and placeholder. Only the first row should be visible. The grid with 4 items also is missing two placeholders in the second row.

Maybe I could use (css)tables? I think there could be a problem with changing column/cell count.

No JS, pure CSS solution preferred.

```js
var widths = [500, 350, 250]
var clicks = 0

$("#changeGridWidth").on("click", function(){
clicks++;
if(clicks===3) clicks=0
$(".grid").width(widths[clicks]);
$("#gridWitdh").text(widths[clicks])

})
```

```css
.grid {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-around;
background: yellow;
width: 500px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid-item {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: green;
margin: 5px;
}

.grid-placeholder {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: grey;
margin: 5px;
}

.grid-placeholder:nth-child(n+5) {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/SIrNqv8h6QGKDuNoLGA4iret+kyesCkHGzVUUV0shc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="gridControl">
<button id="changeGridWidth">change grid witdh</button> (now <span id="gridWitdh">500</span>px)
</div>
<br>
grid with 1 item
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item">
 1
</div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
</div>
grid with 2 items
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item">
 1
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 2
</div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
</div>
grid with 3 items
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item">
 1
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 2
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 3
</div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
</div>
grid with 4 items
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item">
 1
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 2
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 3
</div>
<div class="grid-item">
 4
</div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
<div class="grid-placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: By using placeholders you are creating content where, in fact, there is no content. Dump the idea of placeholders and only use real items (content). If you want to draw the placeholders use a background-image or anything else that's not actual content. Than your problem is solved, because you don't have to tell browser: "this is content that is not content".

Comment: I cant really dump it, because its in the design... Drawing a background is something I thought of, but I think that solution is not so good, because it would have to use an image and introduce other problems.